# C program for stddev/mean

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 100

void calc(float**, int, float*, float*);

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  float *array[MAX];
  float *MEAN;
    float *SD;
    int array_size, i;

    array_size = argc;

    for( i = 0; i < argc ; ++i )
        {
      *array = (float *) malloc( argc*(sizeof(float)));
           *array[i] = atof(argv[i]);
        }

    calc(array, array_size, MEAN, SD);
    return 0;
}

void calc(float* arr[] , int arr_size, float* mean, float* stdev)
{
  int sum, i;

    for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i )
        {
            sum += *arr[i];
        }

    *mean = sum / arr_size;

    printf("%.2f", *mean);

       for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i )
        {
      sum += pow((*arr[i]-*mean), 2);
        }

    *stdev = sqrt((sum/arr_size));

    printf("%.2f", *stdev);

}
```

The code is supposed to determine the mean and standard deviation of a number of user-inputted floats.  I keep getting a segmentation fault when trying to compile it.  I tried freeing malloc but it produced more problems for the code, so I just left it as is - although it's probably a problem with memory distribution.

Thank you

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault when trying to compile it, your compiler is broken.

Comment: Why do you have a `float *array[MAX];`? What’s wrong with a `float array[MAX];`?

Comment: Is Array meant to be an array of float pointers?

Comment: You need to use fewer pointer variables and more variable addresses. Declare `float SD;`, e.g., and `calc(array, array_size, &MEAN, &SD);`.

Comment: @Oswald I've seen gdb and valgrind segfault, but I'd be impressed if someone got gcc to segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `float *array[MAX];` is a pointer to an array of floats. You should
  use either an array of floats or a pointer. Since you are using
  `malloc`, you can use a pointer like this: `float *array;`
- Do not call malloc for each float, but call it once for the entire array
- If you define `MEAN` and `SD` as pointers, you will have to use
  `malloc` on them. It is better to declare them as float only and use
  their addresses (via `&MEAN` and `&SD`).
- You `sum` variable should be a `float`, and you should initialize it
  to `0`. You should also set it to `0` before calculating `stdev`.
- Remember that `argv[0]` contains the name of your program, so
  you should ignore it.
- Also remember to call `free` on anything you allocate with `malloc`
  when you are done with it.

A modified version of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

void calc(float*, int, float*, float*);

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    float *array;
    float MEAN;
    float SD;
    int array_size, i;
    array_size = argc-1;
    array = (float *) malloc( array_size*sizeof(float));
    for( i = 0; i < array_size ; ++i ) {
        array[i] = atof(argv[i+1]);
    }
    calc(array, array_size, &MEAN, &SD);
    free (array);
    return 0;
}

void calc(float* arr , int arr_size, float* mean, float* stdev) {
    float sum=0;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i ) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    *mean = sum / arr_size;
    printf("%.2f ", *mean);
    sum=0;
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i ) {
        sum += pow((arr[i]-*mean), 2);
    }
    *stdev = sqrt((sum/arr_size));
    printf("%.2f", *stdev);
}
```

Comment: `float *array[MAX];` is NOT a "pointer to an array of floats". Pointer to an array of floats is  `float (*array)[MAX];` and it is allocated rather nicely  as `malloc( sizeof (  float[MAX] ) )`  ... That is using VLA in type declaration. Thus cl.exe can not do it. clang or gcc will do.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating and accessing `array` wrongly. Should be like this:

```
for( i = 0; i < argc ; ++i )
{
    array = malloc( argc * sizeof(*array));
    array[i] = atof(argv[i]);
}
```

Also inside `calc()` function change `*arr[i]` to `arr[i]` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely wrong :

```
*array = (float *) malloc( argc*(sizeof(float)));
```

You are allocating an array of floats after declaring the array. This does not make sense. Then you are dereferencing the values wrongly. In addition, in your code your are trying to   transform the name of the program (`argv[0]`) to an int type.

This may be what you wanted to do :

```
float * array = NULL;  

array = malloc( (argc-1)*(sizeof(float))); 

for (i=1; i<argc; ++i)
    array[i]=atof(argv[i]);
```

This code reserves a memory location in the heap of size `(argc-1)*float`, and  initialises it with the values specified as command line parameters. A check should be inserted when `argc` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems,

- check that you have at least one argument
- you declared array as an array of pointers to float, either use `array[]`, or `*array`
- your array need only be allocated once
- allocate an array of number of `samples*sizeof(float)`, once, before loop
- store values read into `array[ndx]` locations (atof is fine)
- argv starts at program name, store into `array[n]` the value converted from `argv[n+1]`
- MEAN and SD need space, you declared pointers, change to value, and pass address (&)

Here is the revised main(),

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    //float array[MAX];
    float *array;
    float MEAN;
    float SD;
    int array_size, ndx;

    if(!(argc>0)) { printf("please give 1 or more arguments\n"); exit(1); }

    array_size = argc-1; //don't count the program name
    array = (float*) malloc(array_size*(sizeof(float)));
    for( ndx = 1; ndx<argc ; ++ndx )
    {
        array[ndx-1] = atof(argv[ndx]);
        printf("[%d] %f\n",ndx-1,array[ndx-1]);
    }

    calc(array, array_size, &MEAN, &SD);
    free(array); array=NULL; //always clean up after yourself
    return 0;
}
```

Your statistics calculations need work, but this at least compiles and runs,

- you need to link against libmath (see below),
- your sum was not initialized, before either loop,
- pow and sqrt return double - read about C math functions and passing double,
- your array_size needs to be set carefully

Here,

```
void calc(float arr[] , int arr_size, float* _mean, float* _stdev)
{
    double sum, mean, stddev;
    int i;

    sum=0.0;
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i )
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        //printf("[%d] %f\n",i,arr[i]);
    }
    printf("sum %f\n",sum);
    *_mean = mean = sum / arr_size;
    printf("mean %f\n",mean);
    printf("%.2f\n", *_mean);

    sum=0.0;
    for ( i = 0; i < arr_size ; ++i )
    {
        sum += pow((arr[i]-mean), 2);
        //printf("[%d] %f\n",i,arr[i]);
    }
    printf("sum^2 %f\n",sum);
    *_stdev = stddev = sqrt((sum/arr_size));
    printf("stddev %f\n",stddev);
    printf("%.2f\n", *_stdev);
}
```

Oh, you want to link to libmath,

```
cc stddev.c -lm -o stddev
```

And when running it,

```
$ ./stddev 1 2 3 4 5
[0] 1.000000
[1] 2.000000
[2] 3.000000
[3] 4.000000
[4] 5.000000
sum 15.000000
mean 3.000000
3.00
sum^2 10.000000
stddev 1.414214
1.41
```

*Also, you need to free the memory you malloc'ed (array).  This is good habit, though not needed for this tiny program.*